# Jquery: Functions Sequential Execution

Tags: jquery

I hope you can help me to solve a little issue about jquery async managment.

the example code i've written is here (it's commented): [Async Jquery Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/TheGeek/t2ej2/)

## Description

Well. I have a bunch of element aligned. They have a function triggered on click that take the current element the previous and the next and animate them to an hight += 50.

## What i Need

I need that the clicks piled up and execute once at time when the last group of element finish their animation.

I make the animation duration random to simulate async event.

## The Problem

### First

Custom queue doesn't autostart . So i need a way to check that there are no animation running before dequeue the queue

### Second

Call the function .is(':animated') on the complete call of the function .animate is pointless.

At that time the element is still set as :animated, so i use a cheap way to resolve the problem calling a setTimeout in the complete function so at the time of setTimeout is triggered the complete function is executed and .is(':animated') is correctly set to false.

I need a better solution becouse there are small window in which the test return true and the dequeue function is triggere twice. (see code comment for a better explanation)

### Third

Despite a sentinel i inject in the queue array (as fx queue does in jQuery), there is a short window of time that trigger the dequeue when it shouldn't (read code comment for a better explanation, i know again) due to the lack of sync lock in javascript language.

## Personal Comment

Yes i know that jquery is threadless language but i need a way to sync this animation in a robust way.

### Bottom Line

Any comments, solutions or thoughts are welcomed ...

Comment: I landed on the similiar problem. have you resolved it yet. If so can you share it so I can refer it to resolve it..Thanks